# How to use resources from compiled libraries in android?

Tags: android, android-library

I'm using appcompat library (gradle: "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'")

Can I use resources from this library? I just want to set popup menu icon for my cards. Menu icon from toolbar and popup menu icon in the cards must be the same.